# Hibernate @OneToMany subselect native query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity with @OneToMany relationship to a list of second entity.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "PAYLD_ID")
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private List<KeyValueEntity> kvList;
```

So the subquery is done separately. My issue is how can I run my own query on subselect as I need to resolve some crossreferences?

I'd like to be able to, whenever the subquery gets executed for List to provide my own native or named query.
Can that be done in Hibernate (using version 4.2.21)?

Main entity is using native query:

```
Payload {

long id;
string cd
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)

List<KeyValueEntity> kvList;
```

}

Named native query (short for brevity):

```
 select pl.id, sct.cd from payload pl join SCT sct on sct.CSN = pl.TCSN
```

When the subquery gets executed to retrieve the kvList via the @OneToMany relationship, I see this query:

```
select kv.pl_id, kv.keycode, kv.value from KV kv where kv.pl_id=?
```

However, I'd like to change the subquery (the above) to :

```
select kv.pl_id, sct.CD, kv.value from KV kv join SCT sct on kv.keycode=sct.CDN where kv.pl_id=?
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What do you mean under `whenever the subquery gets executed for List to provide my own native or named query`. You want to correct this subquery somehow or you want to run some additional query?

Comment: Yes, I want to correct the subquery. Instead of select * from KeyValueEntity, I want to do a join with another table to convert a value, eg select SCT. keyCode, ... from KeyValueEntity join SCT on...

Comment: Could you please describe in detail what model do you have (just add this information to your question). It looks like you should correct you mapping but without information about model it difficult to say how exactly.